# SharePoint Hybrid Search - Find published News in SPO

Tags: 2016, display-template, hybrid-search, sharepoint-news

SharePoint Online provides publishing "**SharePoint News**" in modern sites. 
If you use **SharePoint Hybrid Search** you can find content from SPO on premise and vise versa.

I would like to provide a Display Template on premise for news posted in SharePoint Online. "SharePoint News" are just modern pages that have been published as News. So you can find them when searching for `contentClass:STS_ListItem_WebPageLibrary` as every other web page.

What property marks a web page as published as SharePoint News? Got the "SharePoint 2013 search query tool 2.2" but I cannot find any property that makes me recognize news at all.

Comment: If Promoted State equal 2 page is published as News. Try with that managed property "Promoted State" ;)

Comment: @MarkoTica you are the man! That is right! Want to post this sentence as answer? Would like to mark as right solution and upvote you for this! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Promoted State equal 2 page is published as News. Try with that managed property "Promoted State" ;)